# Solr apply regex on filename to Search case-insensitive

Tags: regex, solr

Updated-----

This works id:/.*ACI[^/]*/ for searching only the filenames, but this is case sensitive as id field is string not text_general, is their a way it can be made case-insensitive without re-indexing the whole data ??

---

I want to apply regex to search only on filename instead of complete path.
My Solr has set of fields, i want to apply on id field which looks like :

```
"id":"TestArea/Destination/SUP000008/COM-1AMLYNI01D0-0001/ACI # Feed/Notes_SpecialFiles_NGDMS.txt",
```

From Solr UI , i apply on fq as: `id:*ACI*`, but it search whole id value and if it finds "ACI" anywhere

It give me the results but i want to apply this fq only on filename that is "Notes_SpecialFiles_NGDMS.txt", how i can achieve the same, what regex i should put in fq filter for same?

Comment: If you only want it when it's defined as in the question - couldn't you search for `id:"/ACI *"` instead? You can also apply a wildcard on the end of the path, i.e. `*/Notes_SpecialFiles_NGDMS.txt` as the `fq`. Make sure the field is a string field.

Comment: This id:"/ACI *" does not work, because it did not know at which level the filename is, i think approach should be first get the filename and then apply regex on same on fq

Comment: According to [this](https://javadeveloperzone.com/solr/solr-regular-expression-part-1/#Anchoring) Lucene patterns are always anchored to beginning and end of the line, so this expression could work: `.*ACI[^/]*`. In words: match ACI only, if it is followed by characters that are not a slash, if any, until the end of the string.

Comment: i applied on fq and gives error - "msg":"org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Cannot parse 'id:.*ACI[^/]*': Encountered \" \"]\" \"] \"\" at line 1, column 32.\nWas expecting:\n    \"TO\" ...\n

Comment: I would assume you have to use delimiters `/.../` to frame the sequence as a regular expression, i.e. `fq=id:/.*ACI[^/]*/`. Maybe you'd have to escape the forward slash inside the negated character class, too: `[^\/]`.

Comment: I also strongly recommend doing this _when you're indexing the content_, and not when searching. The content should be pre-processed as much as possible to support the queries you need, instead of having to work around issues with queries by using query regex-es. Instead, try to get the relevant information into their own fields when indexing (either in your client code, or if not avoidable, with regular expression filters for the fields in their indexing chain)

Comment: @oriberu : Thanks, This works id:/.*ACI[^\/]*/, but this is case sensitive as id field is string not text_general, is their a way it can be made case-insensitive without re-indexing the whole data ??

Comment: @user662285 I'm not familiar with the workings of solr, so I can't help you there; as far as the expression is concerned, you could possibly use character classes to represent `ACI, aci, ...`, since I doubt the case insensitive flag is supported. So, try something like `/.*[aA][cC][iI][^\/]*/`.